# Room database insert error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room database version 1.0.0 , and I created this BaseDao :

```
abstract class BaseDao<in T : BaseDataObject> {


@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
abstract fun insert(entity: T): Long

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
abstract fun insert(vararg entity: T): List<Long>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
abstract fun insert(entityList: List<T>): List<Long>

@Update
abstract fun update(entity: T): Int

@Update
abstract fun update(vararg entity: T): Int


@Delete
abstract fun delete(entity: T): Int

@Delete
abstract fun delete(vararg entity: T): Int
```

}

All of these methods except one works fine, problem is - the one with the `entityList : List<T>` parameter causing the error `Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it. java.util.List<? extends T> entityList);`. But i am using this method from  subclass, and I am definitely annotated entity class with @Entity.

Subclass :

```
@Dao
abstract class ArticleDAO : BaseDao<Article>() {

}
```

Entity class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_article", foreignKeys = arrayOf(
        ForeignKey(
                entity = NewsList::class,
                parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                childColumns = arrayOf("newsListId")))
)
class Article : BaseDataObject() {


    @Embedded(prefix = "source_")
    var source: Source? = null

   //...

}
```

I think that the problem might be in java code, in which Kotlin is translating, because in java code all the other method's parameters are with type `T`, but the broken one has `List<? extends T>`, so i think problem is in the wildcard, but i don't know how to deal with it.